# Nothing is visible anymore and I want to know how to make it visible again

Tags: function, processing

I've been working on this for almost two weeks and I still can't get it to work, I want to know how to make it appear on the screen because the stars and planets pop up without a problem, but once I added the text code everything wasn't visible on the screen anymore. I want to know how to make everything visible on the screen again:

```
def setup():
 size (700, 700)
 background('#0c1445')

#stars
fill('#fbf4d9')
circle(300, 300, 9)
circle(460, 240, 9)
circle(500, 680, 9)
circle(28, 64, 9)
circle(150, 530, 9)
circle(50, 340, 9)
circle(600, 590, 9)
circle(280, 100, 9)
circle(450, 600, 9)
circle(440, 400, 9)
circle(580, 120, 9)
circle(590, 330, 9)
circle(160, 140, 9)
circle(280, 640, 9)
circle(290, 500, 9)
circle(170, 350, 9)
circle(45, 630, 9)

#arrow key 1
arrowone = createShape(GROUP)
#make two shapes
leftpoint = createShape(TRIANGLE, 150, 520, 130, 545, 150, 570)
labody = createShape(RECT, 150, 530, 54, 20)
#add the two "child" shapes to the parent group
arrowone.addChild(leftpoint)
arrowone.addChild(labody)

#arrow key 2
arrowtwo = createShape(GROUP)
#make two shapes
rightpoint = createShape(TRIANGLE, 504, 520, 524, 545, 504, 570)
rabody = createShape(RECT, 450, 530, 54, 20)
#add the two "child" shapes to the parent group
arrowtwo.addChild(rightpoint)
arrowtwo.addChild(rabody)

#show keys
shape(arrowone)
shape(arrowtwo)

def display(itself):
#sun
 fill('#FDB813')
 circle(350, 250, 200)

 #planet one(neptune)
  fill('#4b70dd')
  circle(635, 250, 70)

 #planet two(mercury)
  fill('#e5e5e5')
  circle(75, 250, 20)

 #planet three(venus)
  fill('#a57c1b')   
  circle(125, 250, 40)

 #planet four(mars)
  fill('#ad6242')
  circle(275, 250, 30)

 #planet five(uranus)
  fill('#e1eeee')
  circle(550, 250, 80)

 #planet six(saturn)
  fill('#ead6b8')
  circle(450, 250, 90)

 #planet seven(jupiter)
  fill('#bcafb2')
  circle(350, 250, 100)

 #planet eight(earth) 
  fill('#34A56F') 
  circle(200, 250, 50)

#attempt to make something interactive(p1)
def draw():
 fill('#D0D0D0')
 textSize(30)
 textAlign(CENTER)
 text(fillVal)
def keyPressed():
        global fillVal
        if keyCode == Coded:
            if keyCode == LEFT:
                fillVal = ("Did you know that space is silent?", 350, 450)
            elif keyCode == RIGHT:
                fillVal = ("Did you know that there are more trees on earth than there are stars in the    milky way", 350, 450)
            else:
                fillVal = ("Fun facts about space!", 350, 450)

#making the keys work?
```

I kept rewriting the def setup(): part and the attempt to make something interactive part but it still isn't working..

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to merge newer code with older code into a single sketch.

The best approach in this case is to test each part independently and make sure no mistakes slipped through first.

Afterwards, go through your code and remove anything that isn't necessary (or in case you found something broken, remove the broken parts of the code first).

Finally you should go ahead and merge the code, adding one section at a time, and running it to test, before adding the next. This will make it easier to isloate the issue.

FWIW, here are a few issues I've spotted with the code above:

- formatting is inconsistent. In Python indenting/formatting is crucial. Please  work on forming a habbit to consistently indent code
- some instrunctions seem to be in the global scope when you might have wanted them in the scope of a function.
- `itself` is ambiguous: sounds similar to `self`, however you are not using classes, so you probably doesn't apply. It doesn't seem to be used anywhere as a function argument, so if you don't need it, simply remove it to simplify your code
- `global` usage is not consistent. you should proably define `fillVal` as a global variable, then reuse the keyword in `draw()` to reference the updated variable. (You might want to do the same for the arrows)
- you can group multiple instrunctions in a function. (You're already doing that with `display`. you could do something similar for drawing stars)

Here's a modified version of your code:

```py
arrowone = None
arrowtwo = None
fillVal = "Fun facts about space!"

def setup():
    size (700, 700)
    background('#0c1445')
    noStroke()
    #arrow key 1
    global arrowone,arrowtwo
    arrowone = createShape(GROUP)
    #make two shapes
    leftpoint = createShape(TRIANGLE, 150, 520, 130, 545, 150, 570)
    labody = createShape(RECT, 150, 530, 54, 20)
    #add the two "child" shapes to the parent group
    arrowone.addChild(leftpoint)
    arrowone.addChild(labody)
    #arrow key 2
    arrowtwo = createShape(GROUP)
    #make two shapes
    rightpoint = createShape(TRIANGLE, 504, 520, 524, 545, 504, 570)
    rabody = createShape(RECT, 450, 530, 54, 20)
    #add the two "child" shapes to the parent group
    arrowtwo.addChild(rightpoint)
    arrowtwo.addChild(rabody)

def drawStars():
    #stars
    fill('#fbf4d9')
    circle(300, 300, 9)
    circle(460, 240, 9)
    circle(500, 680, 9)
    circle(28, 64, 9)
    circle(150, 530, 9)
    circle(50, 340, 9)
    circle(600, 590, 9)
    circle(280, 100, 9)
    circle(450, 600, 9)
    circle(440, 400, 9)
    circle(580, 120, 9)
    circle(590, 330, 9)
    circle(160, 140, 9)
    circle(280, 640, 9)
    circle(290, 500, 9)
    circle(170, 350, 9)
    circle(45, 630, 9)
    

def display():
    drawStars()
    #sun
    fill('#FDB813')
    circle(350, 250, 200)
    
    #planet one(neptune)
    fill('#4b70dd')
    circle(635, 250, 70)

    #planet two(mercury)
    fill('#e5e5e5')
    circle(75, 250, 20)
    
    #planet three(venus)
    fill('#a57c1b')   
    circle(125, 250, 40)
    
    #planet four(mars)
    fill('#ad6242')
    circle(275, 250, 30)
    
    #planet five(uranus)
    fill('#e1eeee')
    circle(550, 250, 80)
    
    #planet six(saturn)
    fill('#ead6b8')
    circle(450, 250, 90)
    
    #planet seven(jupiter)
    fill('#bcafb2')
    circle(350, 250, 100)
    
    #planet eight(earth) 
    fill('#34A56F') 
    circle(200, 250, 50)

#attempt to make something interactive(p1)
def draw():
    global arrowone, arrowtwo, fillVal
    
    background(0, 0, 32)
    display()
    #show keys
    shape(arrowone)
    shape(arrowtwo)

    fill('#D0D0D0')
    textSize(30)
    textAlign(CENTER)
    text(fillVal, 350, 450)

def keyPressed():
    global fillVal
    if keyCode == LEFT:
        fillVal = "Did you know that space is silent?"
    elif keyCode == RIGHT:
        fillVal = "Did you know that there are more trees on earth than there are stars in the    milky way"
    else:
        fillVal = "Fun facts about space!"
```

Don't let the above issues discourage you. It's part of the learning process.
Well done on using creating shapes and reusing them by the way.
Best of luck learning to code and have fun!